# How to extend or update a resolver to allow backwards compatibility when a column changed a name in a database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, apollo

I'm working on a project with Node, GraphQL, and PostgreSQL.
I have this situation where I have a column in my DB which needs to be changed to a new name as the scope changed for example from `contact` to `contact_hours`.

My problem is that I have to maintain backward compatibility that means I've been using until now `preferredContact` and the new field is `preferredContactHours`. To avoid miss services what is expected is to make sure whenever something uses `preferredContact` it is hitting `preferredContactHours` so the data will be shown as always be.

I did the change in DB and I did a clone of the type inside my GQL file as follow:

```
type Candidate {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  contacts: [Contact]
  "Deprecated: Use the new preferredContactHours"
  preferredContact: String 
  "New naming: The hours the candidate prefers to be contacted"
  preferredContactHours: String
  }
```

and in my resolver.js I did the same as following under a mutation script:

```
setCandidateContactDetails(
      _,
      {
        input: {
          candidateId,
          // Deprecated: Use the new preferredContactHours
          preferredContact,
          // New naming: The hours the candidate prefers to be contacted
          preferredContactHours,
          ...
      },
      ctx
    ) {
      return CandidateService(ctx).updateCandidate({
        candidate: {
          id: candidateId,
          // Deprecated: Use the new preferredContactHours
          preferredContact,
          // New naming: The hours the candidate prefers to be contacted
          preferredContactHours,
          ...
      });
```

Now I need to make a change inside the mutation of Candidates to actually make sure when anything uses `preferredContact` in reality filter the `preferredContactHours`.

this part I have a problem as I'm new to GraphQL and I don't know how to make it.
What I have now in the specific mutation is as follow:

```
Candidate: {
    comments(candidate, _, ctx) {
      return CommentService(ctx).getComments({
        filter: { candidateId: candidate.id },
      });
    },

    status(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return StatusService(ctx).getCandidateStatus(candidate.id);
    },
    activities(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return CandidateActivityService(ctx).getActivity({
        id: candidate.id,
        actions: args.actions,
      });
    },
    contacts(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return ContactService(ctx).getContacts({
        filter: {
          candidateId: candidate.id,
        },
      });
    },
    nextCall(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return ScheduleService(ctx).getNextSchedule({
        candidateId: candidate.id,
        type: 'CALL',
      });
    },
    nextVisit(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return ScheduleService(ctx).getNextSchedule({
        candidateId: candidate.id,
        type: 'VISIT',
      });
    },
    allowedStatusChanges(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return StatusService(ctx).getAllowedStatusChanges({
        id: candidate.id,
        rule: 'allowed',
      });
    },
    rejectionStatus(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return StatusService(ctx).getAllowedStatusChanges({
        id: candidate.id,
        rule: 'rejection',
      });
    },
    notes(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return NoteService(ctx).getNotes({
        candidateId: candidate.id,
        questionnaireId: args.questionnaireId,
      });
    },
    allowedActions(candidate, args, ctx) {
      return StatusService(ctx)
        .getCandidateStatus(candidate.id)
        .then(status => statusAllowedActions[status.type]);
    },
  },
```

I got a suggestion to make a new entry in the above snippet as an example

```
contactsHours(candidate) {
      return ContactService().getContacts({
        <Something here ???>
      });
    },
```

But I don't know what I should do in this case as my knowledge of GQL is limited.

The expected query when someone wants candidate info to show as an example

```
    Query
     {
      candidate(id: "000") {
        name
        preferredContact
      }
    }
result
"data": {
    "candidate": {
      "name": "xxxx",
      "preferredContactHours": "8-12",
    }
  },
```

I can replace also in the query above with `preferredContactHours` and have the same data result.

In case is need it some more explanations or code please comment with the requests I will update the post for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

'deprecated' means still valid, new option working in parallel to existing one preserving all functionality.

- querying for both values should be valid;
- both should be working separately including filtering;
- you can copy old input value into new one on write (if new not provided);
- you can read/provide old DB field value as result of new field if no value (old records);

**Returning `preferredContactHours` instead of queried `preferredContact` is NOT VALID in graphql** - server should not work this way, it must return values for all queried properties.

Comment: ok cannot you update your answer with a possible solution to my scenario that would be great to get more on it

Comment: sorry, no time today for that ... add some conditions/prepare args/input values before passing to DB/service or update data fetched from DB/service before return from resolver ... you can also try to update written/read data in service/middleware (almost not touching resolvers) ... depends on implementation details

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around if you running Postgres 12. Postgres 12 provides for generated columns thus you can add your new column name essentially as an "alias" to the existing. Basically

```
alter table ta add column 
      preferredContactHours {datatype} 
      generated always as (preferredContact) stored;
```

Where {datayype} corresponds to the data type of preferredContact. Now you can access the data value by either name. Along with the release of this your release notes should indicate:

**"preferredContact has been deprecated in preference of preferredContactHours and will be removed in *release number or date* Any application not updated to access preferredContactHours by then will fail".**

How you handle this in your obfuscation layer (Node, GraphQL, etc) I sorry, but I do not know. Good Luck.